Rotate object to point another object with Geometry Nodes
I have a simple setup scene, as shown below:

The mesh is called "Arrow" and the cube is called "Empty".
Now all I want to do is rotate the Arrow so that it's Z points toward the Empty using Geometry nodes. I've managed to rotate it about the Y axis with the following setup:

The green node "Rotazione Y" has the following:

And the result is the following:

The problem is, if I try to apply the same logic for the Axis X, the overall rotation is wrong.
How can I manage to rotate the object's X and Y in order to point the Empty object?
NOTE: I've noticed that the second input of the node "Rotazione Y" is wrong (should be called Z value, not Y value).

Unless you are willing to dig into math, I would recommend to use an Align Euler to Vector node to align the arrow Z axis to the vector joining both objects origin. Then rotate the arrow mesh with a Transform Geometry node.

Alignment direction may be unexpected. Therefore, if the direction is incorrect, try adjusting the X, Y, Z coordinates of the "Align Euler to Vector" node or swap the inputs to the "Subtract" node (Vector Math)


Great, you made me feel so dumb... I just couldn't imagine the solution was so simple. Thank you!
